How do you check the validity of an sshd_config file?
sshd has a -t (or -T) option:

-t      Test mode.  Only check the validity of the configuration file and sanity of the
keys.  This is useful for updating sshd reliably as configuration options may
change.

But... this only works if the sshd service is already running, which is a bit pointless. If it's stopped, you get a Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd error message.
You can get sshd -t to work if you manually create the /var/run/sshd directory before running the test, but this is clearly not an ideal solution (sshd creates this directory when it starts). Any ideas?

Smells like a bug to me, perhaps you should report it.
I think the intent was that you have it running, change the config file, and then check if it's ok before restarting rather than restarting immediately and having it crash and cause down time.
But if it's not running, may as well start it and see if it fails. You could start it with sshd -d to start it in debug mode and see the errors immediately.  And if it works, you can stop it and restart it normally.

I think you're right about the intent. The problem here is that I'm constructing the config file in a script (sshd is not initially running), and I'm not really happy with starting/restarting to check for errors in the script or input. But maybe I have to.

Your inference about the intent seems to be supported by the default ssh.service file - which apparently runs /usr/sbin/sshd -t as both ExecStartPre and ExecReload

It still shouldn't crash for something that isn't a config error.  systemd probably precreates the temp dir too.
